# tkFileDialog.askdirectory() mangles unicode directory

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having a problem on Windows using `tkFileDialog.askdirectory()` if the directory has non-ASCII characters.

Here's an example:

```
import tkFileDialog
# Open folder C:\notused\weekly\1\Music\岩崎 琢
# (But while the dialog is open, the dialog itself shows the name mangled
# as "C:\notused\weekly\1\Music\?? ?")
o_result = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
# Return result is unicode, which is correct..
print type(o_result)
# ...but the result string has the non-English characters mangled.
print o_result
# And it's not just the display, they seem to be actually mangled.
print ord(o_result[-1])
# The ordinal value of the final character is the same as the question-mark
print ord('?')
```

I notice that the dialog itself shows the mangled string before I ever touch it (which tells me that it's not a processing error on my part), but I can't find any additional parameters or settings to change to make `askdirectory()` work correctly for this case.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had a time with the tkFileDialog under Windows, finally resolved my issue with filename parsing using this:

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter.wantobjects = 0
```

Note that I was using `askopenfiles()` and not `askdirectory()` but maybe it'll work for your situation.

Comment: During a quick test it didn't look like this worked, but I'll try again later when I have more time.